# Problem with Synchronization

Tags: java

I have the following sample piece of code,

```
public class test implements Runnable{

  public void run()
  {
    synchronized(this)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    Thread t=new Thread(new test());
    t.start();

    //Thread.sleep(100);
    t.suspend();
    System.out.println("Hi");
  }
}
```

I have the following requirement,When the thread is suspended it must execute all the iterations of the loop without getting suspended. I felt that synchronized is for this purpose but it didnot solve the problem. When i suspend a thread if it is in a synchronized block then it must get suspended only after the block is executed. What java construct can be used for this?

Comment: Note that Thread.suspend() is deprecated. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, when a piece of code is in `synchronized` block, only one thread can execute this block at once. In order to suspend a thread only after it has finished its synchronized block, just synchronized over the same variable:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) { 
            // some work
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Test target = new Test();
        Thread t = new Thread(target);
        t.start();

        synchronized(target) {
            t.suspend();
        }
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Note that both blocks in `run()` and `main()` synchronize over the same variable (instance of `Test`). Now the code in synchronized block in `main()` will be executed only after the work in `run()` is done.

(Please note however, that there is some race condition here: you cannot guarantee that after `t.start()` the code in `run()` will actually execute before the next line of code in `main()`)

Comment: while this does work, suspending threads for concurrency control is not good threaded design, and is inherently prone to deadlock. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @mdma I agree it's bad. I didn't want to question the design, instead to provide a working solution.

Comment: Sure, I've done the same thing myself a few times! Just wanted the OP to be aware of this in case he's thinking of using Thread.suspend() in production systems.

Answer (score 0):

`suspend()` pauses the thread's execution right where it is. It's usually not a good idea to do this from program code, since the thread will still hold on to any monitors, locks, resources etc.

Instead, use synchronization primitives that block the thread when you don't want it to execute. For example, a Semaphore can be used to cause a thread to wait:

```
public class test implements Runnable{

final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore();

public void run()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            System.out.println(i);
        semaphore.acquire();   // possibly block on the semaphore
        semaphore.release();   // release our lock, we don't need it anymore
    }    
}

public void suspend()
{
   semaphore.acquire();
}

public void resume()
{
   semaphore.release();
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    Test test = new test());
    Thread thread = new Thread(test);
    thread.start();

    // at some point in the future you want to pause execution
    test.suspend();

    // hi will either appear before all of Test's output, or after. but not inbetween.
    System.out.println("Hi");

    test.resume();
}
```

You can also use Locks and [Condition](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to achieve the same thing, but it's slightly more code so we use Semaphore's here to keep it simple.

By not suspending the thread directly, but blocking it instead, you open up to the possibility of using Executors, ThreadPools and other types of thread management (e.g. ForkJoinPool, SwingWorker etc..)